# Bricked USB Thumb Drive - Can it be revived?

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, format

I have a Kingston DataTraveler 3.1 64GB Thumb Drive.  It is now a tiny brick, but unlike other bricked thumb drives in other questions...

Nautilus, Gparted and Disks do not see it.  No recognition of its insertion or removal seems to take place, yet...

```
lsusb
```

reports:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0159 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5159 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler G4
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:62c0 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:00e1 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 Reciever
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

That's it identified at the second entry.  Can this be made to work?  Does Ubuntu remember it and name it or is it reporting it's name and therefore not COMPLETELY bricked?

The drive is similarly ignored on a Mac but, to my immediate surprise, Windoze has recognised it!  I nearly didn't check.  It sees it as 0 bytes and unformatted, but offers to format it.  I haven't tried yet.  Anyone care to work out why Windows does better in this case and tell me if this can be revived using Linux.  From memory, there are encoded backups on there, but I don't mind losing the data.  This is now just a learning/teaching Linux opportunity.  There is a chance that this has been an encrypted drive that I could guess the password for...

Thanks!

edit for @Mark Williams and other interested parties: `dmesg` reports:

```
[36773.888116] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[36774.201457] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666
[36774.201471] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[36774.201479] usb 1-4: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[36774.201486] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Kingston
[36774.201493] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 94DE807246B3EF5159B6E02F
[36774.202512] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[36774.203011] scsi7 : usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[36775.291961] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[36775.293850] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[36776.972191] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 122915328 512-byte logical blocks: (62.9 GB/58.6 GiB)
[36776.972949] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[36776.972965] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[36776.973696] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[36776.973712] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[36777.014732]  sdc: sdc1
[36777.022713] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: What does `dmesg` (from command prompt) have to say about insertion events? (i.e. insert it, type `dmesg` & look at the last few lines of log file - any mention of /dev/sd-whatever?) If that does happen, then we're on - if not, I'd let Windows have a crack!

Comment: `dmesg` output included.  I'd love to learn about Linux rather than just using Windows

Comment: dmesg is the system log (or one of them..) & reports events - such as drive insertions - and helps to show the events & errors. The fact that it sees an event, and reports a drive allocation & no error, is good - the stick is not a brick! It still may have problems which prevent it being any good, but we have something to work with.

Comment: Sounds like it's just broken, especially your comment where dd only copied 500MB out of the drive's 64GB. Any chance of a "lifetime" warranty, returning it, etc? ps. if you hadn't already overwritten it with dd, you could check if it's a LUKS partition/drive with `cryptsetup isLuks <device>`

Comment: Final Answer: It was borked!  Windows saw it but kept claiming that it was write-protected so couldn't format it.  Returned to shop.  Many thanks to all for the help up the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try to find your USB drive with "lsusb", if found,
2. You may try to use dd command to make it nullified "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xxx bs=8M", change XXX with your USB thumb drive ID as found by "lsusb" command.
3. Try gparted to find it and reformat it with your preferred file system.

Ref: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148756

4. Finally, if Windows can handle it, let it do so.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a noob.  From the `lsusb` output in the OP, what exactly is the XXX to be replaced with?  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ bs=0951:1666 8M'`  Is that the ID in place?  Surely not `006` as some devices share that number if they are on different busses, e.g. `002`  Thanks.

Comment: Your USB device seems to be /dev/sdc. However, using dd is pretty dangerous, as you can easily brick your whole system if you use the wrong device! Can you install gparted (if it is not installed yet) and run the following command: `sudo gparted /dev/sdc`. Now, gparted should start, and you should be able to see your 64GB device. If so, you can reformat it using gparted. If it has another size, be sure to double check that it is not one of your harddrives you are formatting!

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not see that you already wrote that gparted can not see it. You could try to verify that it is your stick by looking at the output of `lsblk` you should see that /dev/sdc and /dev/sdc1 are not mounted anywhere, while /dev/sdbX and /dev/sdaX probably are. If you are sure that it is your stick, you can initialize it with zeros running `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=8M

Comment: Oops. Thanks @Gasp0de.  I'll try it, but out of interest, trying to connect with fdisk (what I called Disks in the OP) gives a few of these type errors in dmesg: `[209907.064209] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
`  Therefore, I'm going to try to zero it.  I think that it is duff header info

Comment: Error after `dd` command:    `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=8M' 
`dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdc’: No space left on device`
 `61+0 records in` 
`60+0 records out` 
`507162624 bytes (507 MB) copied, 4.89064 s, 104 MB/s`
The Drive is (or was) 64GB.  Ideas?  Thanks for the continued help!

Answer (score 0):

If the drive is on sdc & the system can't see it, there's a fair chance the partition table is damaged.
You can use `fdisk` (& I'm picking this as gparted fails) to re-write that - from the command line, type `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc`, which brings up a new prompt; type 'g' to create a new GPT table, then 'w' to write it out, re-do the `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` line & type 'p' to print the table - hopefully this will produce a sensible response, & 'n' will be able to add a new partition. If it does, then just accept default start/ end values, 'w'rite it again & see if you can create a formatted drive with `sudo mkfs -t ext2 /dev/sdc1`
If successful, your system may well auto-mount it - or show a new drive icon for you to select.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried fdisk before asking any questions, but called it 'Disks' in the OP.  Gooey Noobs, eh!?  I'm trying @Gasp0de and Arijit's suggestion below...